# Determine proxy type in Delphi XE7

Tags: delphi, proxy, network-programming, indy, delphi-xe7

I am currently working on an application which have to determine the type  (CONNECT, Socks4, Socks5 etc.) of one or more given proxies and connect through them.

Unfortunately I have no approach to reach my goals and hope somebody can help me.

I saw in a tool (GSA SEO Indexer) that this bahvior is somehow possible. The tool has a built-in proxy finder and checker which is able to determine the proxy type:

[image: screenshot of the tool]

I am using Delphi XE7 w/ Indy.

Comment: You should probably test all connection types to decide what works ...

Comment: @smooty86 I considered doing this, but it seems me the most "ugly" way of doing this.

Comment: Well, you *do* have one approach; the one @smooty86 suggested. If you have absolutely nothing now, you could at least *try* that approach and see if it's suitable for you, instead of just presuming it's ugly and doing nothing instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are proxy detection protocols available, such as [WPAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol).  You can use that to obtain details about proxies on a WPAD-enabled network, and then you can connect to them as needed.